# How to find documents from collections and group by that documents in Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor

I want to find documents from collections and group it by some fields and sum it together to return it to the helper.

For example : I have `Sales, SaleDetails` and `Products` Collections and I want to get product name and quantity from saleDetails where Sales is paid.
like SQL Code:

```
SELECT  Products.name as name,
sum(SaleDetails.quantity) AS quantity
FROM (( Sales INNER JOIN SaleDetails ON Sales.Id=SaleDetails.SaleId)
INNER JOIN Product ON Product.Id=SaleDetails.ProductId)
Where Sale.IsPay=true
GROUP BY SaleDetails.ProductId
```

How about with meteor.js?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much you have looked into Meteor to determine how it handles data storage, but it uses MongoDB on the server and a slimmed down interpretation of MongoDB on the client called MiniMongo. MongoDB is a noSQL-based database and therefore does not have the relational data relationships that your SQL query above depends on for querying records from a table. Although it does provide some of the operations that your sample query involves, such as summing and grouping, it does not do joining per se. Although MongoDB is currently on version 3.0, Meteor is still fully invested in 2.6 in order to allow for the kinks in the new version to get worked out. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/) for documentation on MongoDB 2.6. These are some links for the 2.6 versions of the [sum](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and [group](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operations that you reference specifically in your sample query.

I would recommend taking a look at how MongoDB operations work and then take a look at the Meteor documentation for [collection operations](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) to determine if and how you would interpret your sample query in the context of a noSQL database structure. I have to warn you that after coming from a SQL-based world into a noSQL-based world, it is a little difficult to change your way of thinking to not always think in the relational sense, but I'm sure after perusing the documentation for MongoDB and Meteor, it will become much clearer how to structure your data properly to facilitate the usage of MongoDB's various database operations.

Answer (score 0):

Without repeating the other excellent answer from @n4tiv3pwnst4r, first and foremost, Meteor uses MongoDB a noSQL database that does not support transactions and relations.

### BUT....

there are a few strategies available to you.

first, structure your data appropriately, have a look at this intro to [schema design in mongo](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)

Secondly, if you have some of the data already on the client, such as the product, you can create additional pub / subs for the other collections, publishing the data you specifically need, this is a **client side join** and though useful, should be used mindfully, carefully and sparingly.

lastly, we all need relationships sometimes, and .... **theres a package for that** check out [publish with relations](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/publish-with-relations) on [atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/), the package repository for meteor.